# Has anastrophe decreased in frequency during the period of Modern English?

Tags: history-of-literature, literary-device

[Anastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anastrophe), the changing of usual subject-verb-object order for poetic reasons, is something that, anecdotally, strikes me as less frequent nowadays than in older writing from, say, the 19th century. I realise it's a kind of poetic licence that still exists today, but I feel like its frequency has decreased over time, even within the timespan of [Modern English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_English) and leaving aside older authors such as Chaucer etc. But I don't know how to validate this gut feeling; it doesn't seem like something that a simple Ngrams search would verify or disprove, but probably there has been some academic writing about it.

**How has the frequency of anastrophe in poetic writing changed over the last few centuries?** Evidence-based answers only, please.

<sub>This question posted at the suggestion of [Gareth Rees](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23289/can-someone-explain-to-me-these-verses-from-the-faerie-queene/23290?noredirect=1#comment35151_23290) following a discussion in comments.</sub>